# FileDataStore not saving token

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm not sure how to explain this other than to say I have an MVC project I'm trying to get Google Calendar integrated into and I created another MVC project to make sure how things work and test before I get to involved in my main project.

Here's the problem. In my test app, when I grant google permission, the `FileDateStore` stores my token in a file called *`Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-myemail@gmail`* and the contents are json.

But when I ported the code into my main MVC app, ran it, granted google permission, then the `FileDataStore` does something odd. It creates a file that contains a URL and names it *`System.String-oauth_myemail@gmail`*

The one thing I have noticed in the working copy during debugging is that the file starts off as *`System.String-oauth_myemail@gmail`*, but then changes to *`Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Responses.TokenResponse-myemail@gmail`* after I authorize and I get the token response back.

It would seem that on my "broken" app that this isn't getting a token as `result.Credential` comes back null.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
   var result = await new AuthorizationCodeMvcApp(this, new AppFlowMetadata()).
            AuthorizeAsync(CancellationToken.None);
   // other code here
}
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

I'm using this doc as a guide: [OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my attribute based routing was causing havok. I had to add a little conventional routing to get the authcallback to work properly.